# Javascript regex to remove number, then a space?

Tags: javascript, regex

How would I go about removing numbers and a space from the start of a string?

For example, from '13 Adam Court, Cannock' remove '13 '.

Comment: Turns out this was meant to be in PHP instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654617/php-regular-expression-to-remove-number-then-a-space

Comment: delete this question instead. If you can't, you can flag it for mod attention explaining that you asked this in JavaScript by mistake.

Comment: Just flagged the post :)

Comment: You can't delete the question now because there are answers with upvotes. Probably you shouldn't either, since now people wanting to do something like this in JS can refer to this question and its answers.

Comment: I agree with @NullUserException.  Other people will probably find this useful (as evidenced by the upvotes), so we might as well leave it here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Search for

```
/^[\s\d]+/
```

Replace with the empty string. Eg:

```
str = str.replace(/^[\s\d]+/, '');
```

This will remove digits and spaces in any order from the beginning of the string. For something that removes only a number followed by spaces, see BoltClock's answer.

Comment: +1 for fuzzy matching with character classes.

Answer (score 7):

```
str.replace(/^\d+\s+/, '');
```

Comment: Nice rep hike. Last time I checked I was catching up to you, but you got like +1000 rep in the past few days. BTW +1 for an answer giving the OP exactly what they want.

Comment: @NullUserException: LOL I knew you were gonna say that! Yup, you were even well ahead of me just last month ;) *Edit:* looks like your vote's capped my rep for the day!

Comment: Yeah, I've been busy. School just started. It's my last year in college and I want make the most of it. But before that, I want to get to 10k LOL

Comment: @NullUserException: my exams are starting, and since they happen to be programming-related I figured SO would be a nice place to practice and revise — besides my notes. 10k by this week should be easy enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
var text =  '13 Adam Court, Cannock';
var match = /\d+\s/.exec(text)[0];
text.replace(match,"");
```

Answer (score 0):

The above solution doesn't work for me. Instead I used this regex below.

```
var sRegExResult = "Regex Sample99";
sRegExResult.replace(/\s|[0-9]/g, '');
```

Comment: I needed to use a regex to make a nice function name for my Yeoman generator and this was the way to go; above also didn't work for me.

Comment: Thanks @DavidRhoderick. If my answer helps you. Please vote my answer as **helpful**.