# Remove number then a space from the start of a string

Tags: php, regex, replace, trim

How would I go about removing numbers and a space from the start of a string?

For example, from '13 Adam Court, Cannock' remove '13 '

Comment: @Null: I think we'll let the mods decide what to do. Probably merge questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the same regex I gave in my [JavaScript answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654579/jquery-javascript-regular-expression-to-remove-number-then-a-space/3654595#3654595), but apply it using `preg_replace()`:

```
preg_replace('/^\d+\s+/', '', $str);
```

Comment: Hmm it turns out the variable I am running the regex on also spits out a load of HTML, in this instance it would be still be safe to remove all numbers, so would that just be the 'd'? Thanks alot for your response!

Comment: @Probocop: if you want to remove numbers only from the beginning, use `/^\d+/`; if you want to remove all numbers, drop the `^`.

Comment: That's fantastic, thank you very much! (I really need to learn regular expressions when I get time)

Comment: Interesting that you gave *both* me and NullUserException the +15 rep by accepting our different answers on each question. Thanks on our behalf :)

Answer (score 3):

Because everyone else is going the **\d+\s** route I'll give you the brain-dead answer

```
$str = preg_replace("#([0-9]+ )#","",$str);
```

Word to the wise, don't use / as your delimiter in regex, you will experience the dreaded leaning-toothpick-problem when trying to do file paths or something like http://

:)

Comment: Word to the wise, there is no logical reason to avoid forward slashes pattern delimiting characters if the pattern contains no forward slashes.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use

`/^\d+\s+/`

It looks for a **number of any size** in the **beginning of a string** `^\d+`

Then looks for a **patch of whitespace after** it `\s+`

When you use a **backslash before certain letters** it represents something...

`\d` **represents a digit** `0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9`.

`\s` **represents a space** .

Add a plus sign (`+`) to the end and you can have...

`\d+` **a series of digits** (number)

`\s+` **multiple spaces** (typos etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one :

```
^\d+ (.*)$
```

Like this :

```
preg_replace ("^\d+ (.*)$", "$1" , $string);
```

---

**Resources :**

- [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)
- [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)

**On the same topic :**

- [Regular expression to remove number, then a space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654579)
- [regular expression for matching number and spaces.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698950/regular-expression-for-matching-number-and-spaces)

Comment: Capturing the substring after the characters being removed, then adding it back into the string as the replacement string is needless extra work.  The end of string anchor is also not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

The [same regex I gave you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654579/javascript-regex-to-remove-number-then-a-space/3654599#3654599) on your other question still applies. You just have to use `preg_replace()` instead.

Search for `/^[\s\d]+/` and replace with the empty string. Eg:

```
$str = preg_replace(/^[\s\d]+/, '', $str);
```

This will remove digits and spaces in any order from the beginning of the string. For something that removes only a number followed by spaces, see BoltClock's answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the input strings all have the same ecpected format and you will receive the same result from left trimming all numbers and spaces (no matter the order of their occurrence at the front of the string), then you don't actually need to fire up the regex engine.

I love regex, but know not to use it unless it provides a valuable advantage over a non-regex technique.  Regex is often slower than non-regex techniques.

Use `ltrim()` with a character mask that includes spaces and digits.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/kYQfs))

```
var_export(
    ltrim('420 911 90210 666 keep this part', ' 0..9')
);
```

Output:

```
'keep this part'
```

It wouldn't matter if the string started with a space either.  `ltrim()` will greedily remove all instances of spaces or numbers from the start of the string intil it can't anymore.