# How to split a and remove dynamically strings and number from php

Tags: php

Hi i have a json string with some number inside a double quots: how can split it and get exact json string.

```
  $json = "0498[{key:value},{key:value}]"
```

This is pretty simple, but while trying out :(

```
<?php
preg_split('#(?<=\d)(?=[a-z])#i', "0498[{key:value},{key:value}]")
?>
```

But my issue is the integer append to the json is dynamic, it will change time by time so how can i split it?

Comment: [`ltrim($json, "1234567890")`](http://php.net/ltrim) would also work.

Comment: Or [PHP regular expression to remove number then a space?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654617/php-regular-expression-to-remove-number-then-a-space) and leave out the `\s`.

Comment: Thanks Mario :) its working great...super +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$json = preg_replace('~^\d*~', '', '0498[{key:value},{key:value}]');
var_dump($json);
```